# Disable all auto-hyperlink generation Rmarkdown pdf

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Is there a way to disable Rmarkdown's hyperlink generation when producing a PDF document with `toc: yes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
header-includes:
  - \hypersetup{draft}
```

to disable `hyperref`, c.f. http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-50003.1.

Comment: My setup is `includes: in_header: file.tex`, added it to file.tx and it works exactly as expected.